# invalidateOptionsMenu does not recreate items on old APIs

Tags: java, android

I am dynamically styling my inflated menu items on my app on `onCreateOptionsMenu()`. I have a flag which I check and if I want to style them, I proceed. If I do not want to style them, I skip the styling altogether.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu, menu);

    if(mStyleMenu)
       styleMenu(menu);

    return true;
}
```

I use `invalidateOptionsMenu()` to get rid of styling whenever I want. This works on Lollipop and higher system. The style is removed from those menu items. Though, on Kitkat and Jelly Bean (for example), the items keep the style.

I have checked the comment on the `invalidateOptionsMenu()` and it says the items are recreated. So, I cannot explain why this happens on old systems.

Can someone give me a tip on what is going on?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you really need to support Kitkat and Jelly Bean?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: I was mainly curious to see how you're styling those items. Also, have you debugged on the non-functional versions to make sure that your `invalidateOptionsMenu()` call is executing, that `onCreateOptionsMenu()` is indeed running, and that `mStyleMenu` has the expected value when it does?

Comment: Sure thing. We don't really need the complete, actual method; just enough to demonstrate the issue. Now that you've mentioned a `ColorFilter` on a `Drawable`, though, that's a couple of more things that could be going wrong between versions. If I'm understanding your description correctly, and the issue is basically just that with the `Drawable`s, then the first thing I would try  – if you're set up there – would be to `mutate()` the `Drawable` before setting the `ColorFilter`; e.g., `menuItem.getIcon().mutate().setColorFilter(...)`. I'll try to get a test up and running here, in the meantime.

Comment: Oops, wait, sorry. `mutate()` does work. You just need to make sure you do it on all of the icons, especially any that are using the same drawable resource, among themselves, or with any other `View`s anywhere else in your UI. Actually, I should say that it will work with basic `Drawable`s. I seem to recall some other issue with `ColorFilter`s on `StateListDrawable`s back then. Give it a shot, and let me know your results.

Comment: It makes sense. I am convinced. Please write an answer so that I mark. Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: Nice idea, checking that. And now that you mention it, I did inadvertently use a vector for Lollipop+, too. I didn't even think about that. I thought I was using a bitmap resource everywhere. I'll have another look.

Comment: OK, after further testing, I do believe it is still the constant state that's the issue, but it's apparently the difference in how `BitmapDrawable` and `VectorDrawable` handles it. If you use bitmaps on Lollipop+, you'll get the same behavior that you did on KitKat. I misinterpreted what I was seeing, and came to the incorrect conclusion. Sorry 'bout that. `mutate()` is still a viable solution for pre-Lollipop, though. I just need to look into those drawable class differences. I'm not very familiar with `VectorDrawable`.

Comment: Yes, I came to the same conclusion. It is something related to `BitmapDrawable`. I just tested a PNG file instead of `VectorDrawable` and it showed the same behavior on API21 as API19. I believe `mutate()` is indeed the solution here when dealing with old devices and also bitmap drawables. This issue bugged me because I could not explain the odd behavior. I hate that. Now, that I can somehow explain it, I am OK with moving on. Thanks a lot for your time, help, and effort.

Answer (score 1):

To modify your menu at runtime, you must implement the `onPrepareOptionsMenu` function. See [Menus](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus).

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Zelig63. Though, that is not my question. The approach I use works properly since `invalidateOptionsMenu()` causes `onCreateOptionsMenu()` to be called and redraw. I even use it for hiding some items when needed. My question is why the items do not get recreated, on pre Lollipop devices, even though I inflate the menu.